# JQuery Double each function

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two `.school` elements and have 3 `.my-child` elements in each school.

My job is to look for `.my-child` elements in each school and apply a red background for the first child, green for second child and blue for the third.

In each school, my code is to add each .my-child a new class: child1, child2, child3 and apply a background color for each.

Problem: I got as expected in first school, I have .child1, .child2, .child3 added each .my-child.  However, second school, it should be the same: .child1, .child2, .child3, but I got .child3, .child4, .child6.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zjsv47Lw/7/)

```js
$('.school').each(function() {
  $('.my-child').each(function(i, el) {
    $(this).addClass('child' + (i + 1));
  });
})
```

```css
.my-child.child1 {
  background: red;
}

.my-child.child2 {
  background: green;
}

.my-child.child3 {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="school">
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
</div>

<br><br>

<div class="school">
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second line you aren't selecting elements just from within the first selector.

```js
$('.school').each(function() {
  $(this).find('.my-child').each(function(i, el) {
    $(this).addClass('child' + (i + 1));
  });
})
```

```css
.my-child.child1 {
  background: red;
}

.my-child.child2 {
  background: green;
}

.my-child.child3 {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="school">
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You almost got it -- you need to reference the specific element in each `.each()` loop. You did this for the second each, but not for the first one:

```
$('.school').each(function(a, b){
    $(b).find('.my-child').each(function(i, el) {
        $(this).addClass('child'+(i+1));
  });
})
```

[<kbd>**Updated jsFiddle**</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/kd6nq1jt/)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need nested loops, you can just look for the CSS selector `.school .my-child` to select all of these.  If there are no `.my-child` elements anywhere else, you could just select that by itself too.

```js
$('.school .my-child').each(function(i, el) {
    $(this).addClass('child' + (i + 1));
  });
```

```css
.my-child.child1 {
  background: red;
}

.my-child.child2 {
  background: green;
}

.my-child.child3 {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="school">
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Or... if this is always the way it will be, you don't even need JavaScript at all!

```css
.class-room:nth-child(1) .my-child:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
}

.class-room:nth-child(1) .my-child:nth-child(2) {
  background: green;
}

.class-room:nth-child(1) .my-child:nth-child(3) {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="school">
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
  </div>
</div>
```